# My random number sorting algorithm doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm creating this algorithm which is supposed to include numbers `1,2,3,4,5` in an equation which looks like this:

```
@ + ## + ∗ ∗ ∗ + &&&& + $$$$$
```

The symbols meaning that it could be any one of the 5 but each symbol specifying a certain one of them. Then it is supposed to compare, whether the result of the equation is dividable by `11` and if it is then end the loop.

It isn't working, please help.

```js
let cypherNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function randomNum(min, max) { // min and max included 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

for (let n = 0;
  (n / 11 >= 0.0) && (Math.floor(n / 11) === n / 11) && n / 11 != Infinity; n++) {
  function sequence() {
    let selector1 = Math.round(randomNum(1, 5))
    let number1 = cypherNum[selector1]
    cypherNum -= [selector1]
    let selector2 = Math.round(randomNum(1, 4))
    let number2 = cypherNum[selector2]
    cypherNum -= [selector2]
    let selector3 = Math.round(randomNum(1, 3))
    let number3 = cypherNum[Math.round(selector3)]
    cypherNum -= [selector3]
    let selector4 = Math.round(randomNum(1, 2))
    let number4 = cypherNum[Math.round(randomNum(1, 2))]
    cypherNum -= [selector4]
    let number5 = cypherNum[1]
    cypherNum -= [1]
    let num = (number1) + (number2 * 11) + (number3 * 111) + (number4 * 1111) + (number5 * 11111)
  }
  console.log(sequence())
}
```

Comment: The `-=` operator does not do what I think you think it does.

Comment: It looks like you haven't ran your code with a debugger. Why not?

Comment: *"whether the result of the equation is dividable by 11"*: you are never testing the **result**. Instead you are testing the loop variable.

Comment: `Math.round(randomNum(1, 5))`: array indices are zero-based. You'll not ever select index 0, and sometimes select index 5 which is not an existing index in your array. Also, calling `round` serves no purpose, since your `randomNum` already executed a `floor`.

Comment: `console.log(sequence())` - `function sequence` does not `return` a value, so this will always be `undefined`

Comment: Never seen `-=` on an array before... wonder what it does... https://jsfiddle.net/8kyusLr5/  ... ah, returns `NaN`.   Might be a good place to start.   Maybe `cypherNum.splice(i, 1);`  https://jsfiddle.net/8kyusLr5/1/  (remembering that indexes are 0-based of course..)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

- Your random indices are never zero, and could exceed the valid range: array indices start at 0, and have their last index at −1, where  is the array length.
- `-=` does not remove an array entry. You could use the `splice` method to achieve that.
- Your loop condition does not check whether `num` is a multiple of 11, but performs an irrelevant test on `n`.
- Not a problem, but since your `randomNum` already returns an integer, it makes no sense to call `Math.round` on it.

I would suggest to randomise the *order* of your `cypherNum` array in each iteration (shuffle it). Also, the sum could be calculated with a `reduce` call, using the fact that these 1111 coefficients are equal to (10−1)/9 for some value of `i`.

Here is how that could look:

```js
function randomNum(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = randomNum(0, i);
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

const cypherNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const coeff = cypherNum.map((_, i) => (10 ** (i + 1) - 1) / 9); // 1, 11, 111, ....
console.log("coefficients are:", ...coeff);

let num = 1;
let i = 0;
for (i = 0; num % 11; i++) {
    shuffle(cypherNum);
    num = cypherNum.reduce((sum, digit, i) => sum + digit * coeff[i]);
}
console.log(`Found solution after ${i} iterations:`);
const s = cypherNum.map((digit, i) => digit * coeff[i]).join(" + ");
console.log(`${s} = ${num} and ${num} = 11 * ${num/11}`);
```